# WPF - Binding To Read-Only Property - Notification Of Changes?

Tags: wpf

Assume that I have an application with the following structure:

(1) ViewModelA

(2) ReportManager

(3) ViewA

So - first, let me get the obvious out of the way.  ViewA binds to ViewModelA.

Now for the not so obvious.  ViewModelA has a singleton instance of ReportManager injected into it's constructor.  ViewModelA exposes a public read-only property called SomeReport.  The getter for this property points to a property from the singleton instance of the ReportManager.  Consider the following example below:

```
    public ISomeViewModel SomeReport
    {
        get { return _reportManager.SomeReport; }
    }
```

In ViewA, I have a ContentPresenter whose content property binds to the SomeReport property in ViewModelA - and because the SomeReport property in ViewModelA is read-only, I have set the binding up as OneWay.

Any and all changes made to the SomeReport property are made from within the ReportManager class - thus, this property has a private setter.  The problem that I am running into is that the ContentPresenter in ViewA is not registering changes made to the SomeReport  property.

Any help on what I am potentially doing incorrectly would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your ViewModel then signal that SomeReport has changed by calling NotifyPropertyChanged.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx